# pass foreach variable to spark sql to calculate sum in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to pass column names fetched in a array to the spark sql but not sure how do we pass it as a variable.
I have created a dataframe and fetching all columns in a variable x, now I'm creating a foreach loop to create a query string to query on in the next step.
How do we approach this ? The end result should be sum of individual columns in the "dftable". Please help.

```
    df.createOrReplaceTempView(“dftable”)

   // collect an array of columns
   val x=  df.schema.fieldNames

  // create query string for the columns fetched above
   x.foreach { y => "select sum(x) from dftable”}

  // pass variable to query in spark.sql
   spark.sql("select y from dftable”)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For vertical solution: you can union many DataFrames

```
val dfs = x.map(field => spark.sql(s"select '$field' as fieldName, sum($field) from dftable"))
val withSum = dfs.reduce((x, y) => x.union(y)).distinct()
```

Probably this would be helpful

```
val sums = x.map(y => s"sum($y)").mkString(", ")
spark.sql(s"select $sums from dftable");
```

Sums will be in format: "sum(field1), sum(field2)"

You can use DSL also:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val sums = for (field <- x) yield { sum(col(field)) }
df.agg(sums : _*)
```

The result should be exactly the same

Comment: Thanks Shankar and T for your response. The issue is that I want to achieve it through spark sql since it would align data in a table format but not horizontally as Shankar showcased above. I would keep the question open. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @sabby Please see my answer :)

Comment: T.Gaweda you are awesome ! Superb ! just like the way I wanted it to be !  one question, how can be restrict this to be applied only on Integer columns..can we add datatype related restrictions ?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is helpful

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._
val df1 = Seq((1,2,3), (3,4,5), (1,2,4)).toDF("A", "B", "C")
df1.describe().show()


val exprs = df1.columns.map(c => sum(col(c))).toList

df1.agg(lit(1).alias("temp"),exprs: _*).drop("temp")
```

Output:

```
+------+------+------+
|sum(A)|sum(B)|sum(C)|
+------+------+------+
|     5|     8|    12|
+------+------+------+
```